# How to move the product details to a new component when clicked from product list component in angular

Tags: html, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to develop an Angular and Django shopping application.

I have the products coming through from the Django API into the angular products list component but I want to be able to click a product and view the details of that product in a new component.

What I currently have is the list component and when you click a product it will display the details on the same component but I want to replace the list view with the details of the product the user clicks on a specific product.

My Angular project structure is as follows:

App Module > Main Module >
Product Details Component,
Products List Component > Product Item Component

I am new to angular so if this looks like bad a project Structure I'm sorry!

Here is the code:

product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  productList: Product[] = [];
  selectedProduct = null;

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const urToken = this.cookieService.get('ur-token')
    if (!urToken) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    } else {
      this.apiService.getProducts().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.productList = data;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    }

    
  }

  selectProduct(product: null) {
    this.selectedProduct = product;
    console.log('selectedProduct', this.selectedProduct);
  }
}
```

product-list.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col>
    <app-filter></app-filter>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="container pb-5">
      <h2 class="text-center font-weight-light mb-5">Featured products</h2>
        <app-product-item [products]="productList" (selectProduct)="selectProduct($event)"></app-product-item>
    </div><br>
</div>
<div class=row>
<div class=col>
  <app-product-details [product]="this.selectedProduct" (updateProduct)="selectProduct($event)"></app-product-details>
</div>
</div>
```

product-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../../../models/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-item',
  templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.css']
})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() products: Product[] = [];
  @Output() selectProduct = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  productClicked(product: Product) {
    this.selectProduct.emit(product);
  }

}
```

product-item.component.html

```
<div class="row text-center justify-content-sm-center no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3" *ngFor="let product of products" (click)="productClicked(product)">
    <div class="card   shadow h-100 ">
      <div class="card-img-top">
        <img alt="image" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block image" src="{{ product.cover_image }}">
      </div>
      <div class=" card-body p-md-2 ">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a href="#" class=" font-weight-bold text-dark text-uppercase small"> {{ product.name }}</a>
        </h4>
        <p>{{ product.price | currency:"EUR" }}</p>
        <p class="mt-4">
          <a href="#">View &gt;</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

product-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedProduct = null;

  @Input()
  product: any;
  @Output() updateProduct = new EventEmitter();
  
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getDetails() {
    this.apiService.getProduct(this.product.product_code).subscribe(
      product => {
        this.updateProduct.emit(product);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  selectProduct(product: null) {
    this.selectedProduct = product;
    console.log('selectedProduct', this.selectedProduct);
  }

}
```

product-details.component.html

```
<div *ngIf= "product">
    
    <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src="{{ product.product_image }}">
    <h1>{{ product?.name  }} </h1>

    <h2>Product Details</h2>
        <p>{{ product?.price | currency:"EUR" }}</p>
        <p>ID: {{ product?.product_code }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ product?.product_description }}</p>
    <h2>Shop Details</h2>
        <p>Shop: {{ product?.shop.shop_name }} <br>
            Slogan: {{ product?.shop.slogan }}, <br>
            Description: {{ product?.shop.description }}</p>
</div>
```

If anyone could help here that would be great, and if there is something that could be tidied up here that would also be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want to replace the list view with the details of the product the user clicks on a specific product.

Move the ngIf from product-details.component.html to it's parent, include an else template. Dumb example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedProduct; else productSelection">
  <app-product-details [product]="selectedProduct" (updateProduct)="selectProduct($event)"></app-product-details>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #productSelection>
  <app-product-item [products]="productList" (selectProduct)="selectProduct($event)"></app-product-item>
</ng-template>
```